# What is the difference between catch(Exception $ex) and catch(\Exception $ex)?

Tags: zend-framework, exception, try-catch

I'm learning Zend and am still encountering the following try-catch statement. For example:

```
    try {
        $album = $this->getAlbumTable()->getAlbum($id);
    }
    catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album', array(
            'action' => 'index'
        ));
    }
```

I don't understand what is the importance of the backslash "\" symbol in fron of the Exception classname.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the namespacing introduced in PHP 5.3.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php

It's there to stop the Exception being caught by any other namespace it's currently in, and to only use the root namespace which holds the Exception class